# how to integrate vuestorefront with shopify

Tags: vue.js, shopify, storefront, vue-storefront

I am trying to integrate vuestorefront with shopify but unable to understand 
proper way 
 
there are many repositories like 
vue storefront for front end 
https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront 
vue storefront api for back end 
https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront-api 
vue storefront integration boilerplate for 3rd party integration (in our case Shopify ) 
https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront-integration-boilerplate 
this is all I know 
I have problem in vue storefront integration boilerplate 
unable to find a way to communicate with shopify 
docs are saying 
I need to built a new app on any platform that app will communicate with  vue storefront integration boilerplate(vs bridge) and shopify

this is example config for magento in vs bridge(vue storefront integration boilerplate)

```
{
    "elasticsearch": {
        "host": "",
        "indexName": "vue_storefront_magento1"
    },
    "vsbridge": {
        "url": "http://example.com:80/",
        "auth": {
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "password123",
            "secret": "Geiw0qua"
        },
        "auth_endpoint": "http://example.com/vsbridge/auth/admin",
        "product_endpoint": "http://example.com/vsbridge/products/index",
        "category_endpoint": "http://example.com/vsbridge/categories/index",
        "taxrule_endpoint": "http://example.com/vsbridge/taxrules/index",

    }
}
```

i need help in this config file to communicate with shopify 
**Please tell me if anyone has done it**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see is to create a "middleware" app and place it somewhere. This app should be build based on the integration bolierplate examples and server the data fetched from Shopify API.

When this "middleware" or "bridge" app is done. It will be possible to connect it to VueStorefront as the vue-storefront-api replacement.
In vue storefront config you will not provide URLS to the vue-storefront-api but to your own app URLs.

Comment: did you do it? i know this concept and i am trying  but i am stuck at elastic data store and docker etc  failed to understand the flows of data

Comment: yes I successfully built custom integration using the boilerplate, that's how I know :) Feel free to join official vueStorefront slack channel ( https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront#join-the-community-on-slack ) if you have additional questions when SO is not enough anymore or you have simply too many questions. but other than that, just use `vue-storefront` tag and I'll help on SO as much as I can with the other questions you might have.

Comment: Yes i am in vue Storefront slack channel, I will talk you in slack